# Java Arithmetic Coding - Finding Character Ranges

Tags: java, compression, precision, rounding-error

I am trying to recreate a Java implementation of arithmetic coding as described in this link, under the section 'Arithmetic Coding: how it works': [link](http://marknelson.us/1991/02/01/arithmetic-coding-statistical-modeling-data-compression)

I am at the point where the individual symbols need to be assigned a range along a probability line. However, I am having some issues in creating the correct ranges. In my code shown below, this is carried out by setRanges(). The expected result should be this:

```
Character Ranges -

            0.0 - 0.09999999999999999
A           0.1 - 0.19999999999999999
B           0.2 - 0.29999999999999999
E           0.3 - 0.39999999999999999
G           0.4 - 0.49999999999999999
I           0.5 - 0.59999999999999999
L           0.6 - 0.79999999999999999
S           0.8 - 0.89999999999999999
T           0.9 - 0.99999999999999999
```

My current output is this:

Character Ranges -

```
            0.0 - 0.09999999999999999
A           0.1 - 0.2
B           0.2 - 0.30000000000000004
E           0.30000000000000004 - 0.4
G           0.4 - 0.5
I           0.5 - 0.6
L           0.6 - 0.8
S           0.8 - 0.9
T           0.9 - 1.0
```

I am not sure is there is a better way to code my method setRanges(), or whether this is simply the result of rounding errors.

Here is the class Range which simply contains a low and high float value:

```
public class Range {

    private double low, high;

    public Range(double low, double high) {
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return low + " - " + high;
    }

}
```

The method:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

    public static TreeMap<Character, Range> setRanges(TreeMap<Character, Double> treeMap) {
        TreeMap<Character, Range> rangeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        double currentValue;
        double previousValue = 0;
        double runningTotal = 0;

        for(Character key : treeMap.keySet()) {
            currentValue = treeMap.get(key) + runningTotal;
            rangeMap.put(key, new Range(previousValue, currentValue - 0.00000000000000001));
            previousValue = currentValue;
            runningTotal += treeMap.get(key);
        }
        return rangeMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: does it absolutely necessary to change the code because of 0.000000000001 ?

Comment: I have been asked to implement this for schoolwork, the site states 'Note also that the character “owns” everything up to, but not including the higher number. So the letter ‘T’ in fact has the range 0.90 – 0.9999….'

Comment: As you can also read on that tutorial, no one ever actually implements arithmetic coding with decimals. It has all these crazy precision traps that are hard to take care of, and it becomes super slow as the output grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use BigDecimal for that precision. With either 128 or no roudning option. See below:

```
double first = 1d;
double second = 0.00000000000000001d;

System.out.println("Db --> " + (first - second));

BigDecimal firstBd = new BigDecimal(first);
BigDecimal secondBd = new BigDecimal(second);
BigDecimal resultBd = firstBd.subtract(secondBd);

System.out.println("32 --> " + resultBd.round(MathContext.DECIMAL32));
System.out.println("64 --> " + resultBd.round(MathContext.DECIMAL64));
System.out.println("128--> " + resultBd.round(MathContext.DECIMAL128));
System.out.println("Unl--> " + resultBd);
```

Output is:

> Db --> 1.0
>  32 --> 1.000000
>  64 --> 1.000000000000000
>   128--> 0.9999999999999999899999999999999993
>  Unl-->
>   0.9999999999999999899999999999999992845757594537807549147194381507675227382936355979836662299931049346923828125

Comment: The level of precision is arbitrary, the work states 'A double precision floating point data type can be used to store the coded value but be aware that under the IEEE 745 standard the 52 bit mantissa will provide only up to 16 digits of accuracy.  Therefore the length of string to be encoded should be suitably restricted.' I was merely using the negative 0.000000000001 to get the smallest figure a double would allow below the whole number.

Comment: I tested and see, with double 0.0000000000000001d is the limit you can subsctract from 1. Result will be: Db --> 0.9999999999999999 However when you add one more '0' after dot, result becomes: Db --> 1.0 So if first limit sufficient for you, you can ignore BigDecimal solution and keep on using double. This may vary according to 32-64 bit java installation.

Comment: Yes it appears that way, however when I use this in the first range for example I still get 0.0 - 0.09999999999999991, which I assume is just an unavoidable rounding error. Thanks for your help